Initializing const member of the base internal class
Consider following code:
struct Helper
{
    const std::wstring manager;
    // Number of other variables
};

class __declspec(dllexport) Base
{
    protected:
        Helper m_impl;
        int m_id;
        // Number of other variables
    public:
        Base(int id, const std::wstring &manager) : m_id( id ), m_impl.manager( manager )
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int id, const std::wstring &manager) : Base( id, manager ) {}
}

Unfortunately only the id n the Base class can be initialized.
The helper structure was created to avoid the warning about exporting  std::wstring member, but I can't initialize it when it declared like this...

Why not give Helper a constructor?

@StephenNewell, because it is meant to be a simple C-like data holder.

The shown Helper is an aggregate and can be aggregate-initialized.
Since C++20:
  Base(int id, const std::wstring& manager) : m_id(id), m_impl(manager) {}

Until C++20:
  Base(int id, const std::wstring& manager) : m_id(id), m_impl{manager} {}


,,  ``Helpercontains another std::wstring variables but they are not constant and so can be initialized in theDerivedconstructor or later. Now, do I need to create aHelper` constructor which will take just this one parameter?

If manager is a first member, you don't need a constructor. If not a first member, then since C++20: m_impl{.manager = manager}

and if I have a code below C++20?

Please edit your question to make it full of all details, or ask a new question. You've shown a code and got a complete answer. Comments are not for evolving questions.

Thank you. I upvoted your first comment here.

Use {} for members that precede manager.

@Igor https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
